# Mysql Field Data not displaying when a link is clicked?

Tags: php, html, mysql

I'm trying to get data from a database if a link is clicked.

I used the example codes suggested from this example -[Getting mysql field data when a link is clicked?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9499025/getting-mysql-field-data-when-a-link-is-clicked)

But it doesn't work when I click on a link nothing comes up.

**main.php**

```
<?php
include('conn.php');
$sql2    = "SELECT Title FROM addpromo";
$result2 = mysql_query($sql2);

echo "<div id=\"links\">\n";
echo "<ul>\n";
while ($row2 = mysql_fetch_assoc($result2)) {
    echo "<li> <a href=\"fullproject.php?title=\""
        . urlencode($row2['Title']) . "\">"
        . htmlentities($row2['Title']) . "</a>\n</li>";
}
echo "</ul>";
echo "</div>";
?>
```

This is displaying correct.but when I click at a link nothing is showing up in fullproject.php, Just a blank page.

**fullproject.php**

```
<?php
// Connect to server.
include('conn.php');
$projectname = isset($_GET['Title']);
$sql1 = "SELECT Title FROM addpromo WHERE Title = '$projectname'";
$result1 = mysql_query($sql1);

while ($row1 = mysql_fetch_assoc($result1)) {
    echo "Project Name: " . $row1['Title'] . "<br />";
    echo "<br /> ";
}
?>
```

Can someone help me to fix this, or any other way to make this(to get data from a database if a link is clicked) possible?

Comment: change $projectname= isset($_GET['Title']); to $projectname= $_GET['Title']; as isset returns a boolean value

Comment: thanks but when i removed isset its showing an error as Undefined index: Title

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change to this

**main.php**

```
<?php
include('conn.php');
$sql2="SELECT Title FROM addpromo";
$result2=mysql_query($sql2);    

echo '<div id="links">';
echo '<ul>';
while($row2 = mysql_fetch_assoc($result2)){
echo '<li><a href="fullproject.php?title='.urlencode($row2['Title']).'">'.htmlentities($row2['Title']).'</a></li>';

}
echo '</ul>';
echo '</div>';
?>
```

**fullproject.php**

```
<?php

if(isset($_GET['title'])){

    include('conn.php');

    $projectname= $_GET['title'];

    $sql1="SELECT Title FROM addpromo WHERE Title = '$projectname'";
    $result1=mysql_query($sql1);    

    while($row1 = mysql_fetch_assoc($result1)) {
      echo "Project Name: " . $row1['Title']. "<br />";    
      echo "<br /> ";
    }

}

?>
```

Comment: I have a little error in the code (parentheses) but I update my answer

Comment: $sql1="SELECT Title FROM addpromo WHERE Title = '$projectname'"; What is the point of this? You are selecting for example title_x_name WHERE Title = title_x_name

Comment: When you click in the link your url is correct ? fullproject.php?title=selected_title

Comment: Change to this echo '<li><a href=\"fullproject.php?title=',urlencode($row2['Title']),'\">'.htmlentities($row2['Title']).'</a>\n</li>';

Comment: @Melvin Sorry change to this: echo '<li><a href="fullproject.php?title='.urlencode($row2['Title']).'">'.htmlentities($row2['Title']).'</a></li>';

Answer (score 0):

This is storing a boolean value `$projectname= isset($_GET['Title']);`, whether or not the title is set. Instead use `$projectname = $_GET['Title'];`

Comment: thanks but when i removed isset its showing an error as Undefined index: Title

Answer (score 0):

isset returns a boolean value (true/false) and you want the actual value of the variable:

```
$projectname= $_GET['title'];
```

Furthermore, you have to pass only the title as the URL parameter, without enclosing it within quotes. So there is an error in this line:

```
echo "<li> <a href=\"fullproject.php?title=" . urlencode($row2['Title']) . "\">"
```

Note the lack of \" after title=

Comment: thanks but when i removed isset its showing an error as  Undefined index: Title

Comment: Good point, there parameter is sent with lowercase: title. I changed the answer accordingly.

Comment: Ok, found another issue in the code. This time in main.php. I'd suggest the following steps:
1. Check that the URL of the link is OK, including the Title parameter.
2. Debug the received parameters in fullproject.php. For this you can use print_r($_GET).